# How can I restore a PS4 following a hard shutdown (unplug of power)?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I was having a disagreement with someone regarding whose turn it was to play, and I went to shut down the PS4. I pushed the power button twice, but it didn't shut down, so I unplugged the power cord of the PS4.

We went back and forth a bit, plugging the console back in and taking it back out again. Eventually, we turned the PS4 back on and it booted up into safe mode, asking us to perform a re-installation of a software update.

Did we harm the PS4? We bought it one month ago, would we still be covered by the warranty if it has been harmed? Note that it's telling we have corrupted files, and after trying to install the update using a USB drive, error `30634-6` occurs.

How can I resolve this error message?

Comment: @ghinwa Playstation support will be able to help you much more than we will. Try contacting them

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something has become corrupted - your best bet is to try the various 'factory reset' options offered by the PS4's Safe Mode.

To boot to Safe mode, hold down the power button on the console until you hear two beeps. It should take about 8 seconds.

Once you get to Safe Mode, you will get a menu of options. The ones we're interested in are below, you should try them in the order they are presented:

4. **Restore Default Settings** - this will reset everything on the PS4 to its original software settings, but keep your data (profiles, save files etc). Try this first.
5. **Rebuild Database** - while this is more aimed at improving boot times, a little-known fact is that it will remove games and applications from the database that it thinks are 'corrupted'. Running this can take a few hours though.
6. **Initialise PS4** - this will wipe your hard drive (removing downloaded games, applications, save files etc) and restore you to factory settings. The only thing it won't do, is touch the PS4's operating system (system software). You have a choice of doing a 'Quick' or a 'Full' initialisation. Try the Quick one first, then if that doesn't work, move to the Full re-initialisation.
7. **Initialise PS4 (Reinstall system software)** - This is a full wipe of everything, but requires you to download the PS4 system software onto an external device.

   - Get the '*PS4 reinstallation file*' here: https://www.playstation.com/en-au/support/hardware/ps4/system-software/. Note you need the *reinstallation* file, **not** the *update* file
   - Get a USB thumbdrive that uses the FAT32 drive format, or [format one yourself](https://superuser.com/q/695367/107240).
   - Create a folder named `PS4` on the USB drive
   - Inside that folder, create another folder named `UPDATE`.
   - Copy the installation file and save it in the `UPDATE` folder. Save the file as `PS4UPDATE.PUP`.
   - Plug the USB drive into the PS4
   - Start the PS4 console in Safe Mode
   - Select Safe Mode option 7: Initialise PS4 (Reinstall System Software).
   - Select Update from USB Storage Device -> OK.

If none of the above options work, then your PS4 is well and truly broken, and you should take it to a computer repair shop to see if they can help. I doubt pulling the plug would be covered by warranty.

#### Sources

- Personal Experience
- [PS4 Reinstallation Instructions - Playstation Support](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/support/hardware/reinstall-playstation-system-software-safe-mode/)
- ['How to factory reset a PS4' - Digital Trends](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-factory-reset-a-ps4/)